# Celebrations, Commemorations,

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay

You start with me with nothing else,
But second time you’re better than first,
Celebrations, commemorations to celebrate,
Your ascendence to a better way,
Though the happiness is good,
And the wisdom is better,
All things have an end,
And this is no exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this about:

> Birthdays/getting older?

Comment: Yes, it is! Well done!